# How to store object In Cookie in React using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project In my project I have a scenario to store object in Cookie.

This is my code Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

const Login = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('')

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target
        const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value })
        setData(newData)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(data)
    }
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <div className='main'>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" name='email' id="email" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name='username' id="username" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" name='password' id="password" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

When I click submit button data will print in console. I have to store that in cookie

So what is the best way to store data object in Cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the cookie in document.cookie. But you need to save the data as a string.
You could parse the whole object with JSON.parse, or the more elegant way is to use the specific attributes.

[Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

But be aware that it is not save to store passwords in cookies.

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

const Login = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('')

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target
        const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value })
        setData(newData)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        document.cookie = `email=${data.email}`; 
        document.cookie = `username=${data.username}`; 
        document.cookie = `password=${data.password}`;  
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <div className='main'>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" name='email' id="email" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name='username' id="username" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" name='password' id="password" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Hi @MaatMa why it is storing only email ? it is not storing username and password

Comment: But like I already wrote, please take a look at JWT (JSON Web Token). It's a much saver way.

Answer (score 0):

You just set data to cookie:

```
document.cookie =
```

of you can use some npm lib like this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie